# How to write a function that manipulates the data structure in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

#### Some background information for better understanding

I have a very specific dataframe. It is basically tha sample of answers on my survey. Variables `v1` represent a multiple choice question; the respondent were to choose variants from 1 to 4, he/she could choose the only or several options. Every chosen variant readressed the respondent to the block: if `1` was chosen, the respondent was readressed to `o_v1_1`, `c_v1_1`, and `f_v1_1` and so on.

#### The problem

I want to write a function that will change my data structure from wide to long. But I am struggling with `pivot_longer`, because it does not produce a desirable output.

Here's the sample dataframe with some initial data processing:

```
structure(list(seance_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), respondent = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), v1...3 = c(1, 1, NA, 1), v1...4 = c(2, NA, 2, 
NA), v1...5 = c(3, 4, 4, NA), v1...6 = c(4, NA, NA, NA), o_v1_1 = c(6, 
1, NA, 4), c_v1_1 = c(7, 1, NA, 1), f_v1_1 = c(8, 1, NA, 1), 
    o_v1_2 = c(10, NA, 4, NA), c_v1_2 = c(8, NA, 1, NA), f_v1_2 = c(3, 
    NA, 3, NA), o_v1_3 = c(4, NA, NA, NA), c_v1_3 = c(1, NA, 
    NA, NA), f_v1_3 = c(2, NA, NA, NA), o_v1_4 = c(10, 5, 4, 
    NA), c_v1_4 = c(9, 6, 5, NA), f_v1_4 = c(9, 6, 6, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

data <- data %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.character)

colnames(data) <- c("seance_id", "respondent", "v1", "v1", "v1", "v1", "o_v1_1",
                    "c_v1_1",   "f_v1_1",   "o_v1_2",   "c_v1_2",   "f_v1_2",   "o_v1_3",   "c_v1_3",
                    "f_v1_3",   "o_v1_4",   "c_v1_4",   "f_v1_4")
```

And here's how I tried to make my table long:

```
long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`seance_id`, names_to = "v1", values_to = "answer")
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
  `séance_id` respondent direction answer_dir criteria criteria_answer
        <dbl> <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
1           1 A          v1                 1 o_v1_1                 6
2           1 A          v1                 1 c_v1_1                 7
3           1 A          v1                 1 f_v1_1                 8
4           1 A          v1                 2 o_v1_2                10
5           1 A          v1                 2 c_v1_2                 8
6           1 A          v1                 2 f_v1_2                 3
```

I have been researching SO for 2 days already and have not resolved my problem yet. How can I use `pivot_longer` effectively to get the desirable output? And is there any way to automate the process of longing my dfs? I have more than 30 of dfs, nested in different lists within one Excel file.

Comment: Can you help me understand why you are labeling four columns `v1` in your source table? Do they mean different things? Won't that tend to lead to ambiguities?

Comment: @JonSpring I am trying to mimic my original dataframe. I understand that it might bring some problems... Maybe beacuse of that I am struggling with making my table long

Comment: What do they mean and how do you want to use them?

Comment: @JonSpring ```v1``` represents a multiple choice question. The architecture of the survey platform does not allow me to recode respondents choices in a form of column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop you initial `v1` columns. I instead propose the following:

```
 data %>% select(-starts_with('v1')) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = contains('v1'), names_to = "v1", values_to = "criteria_answer") %>% 
   separate(v1, sep='_', into=c('w','direction','answer_dir'), remove=FALSE) %>%
   rename(creteria=v1) %>% select(-w)
# A tibble: 48 x 6
   seance_id respondent creteria direction answer_dir criteria_answer
   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     <chr>      <chr>          
 1 1         A          o_v1_1   v1        1          6              
 2 1         A          c_v1_1   v1        1          7              
 3 1         A          f_v1_1   v1        1          8              
 4 1         A          o_v1_2   v1        2          10             
 5 1         A          c_v1_2   v1        2          8              
 6 1         A          f_v1_2   v1        2          3              
 7 1         A          o_v1_3   v1        3          4              
 8 1         A          c_v1_3   v1        3          1              
 9 1         A          f_v1_3   v1        3          2              
10 1         A          o_v1_4   v1        4          10             
# ... with 38 more rows
```

The final `select(-w)` is to remove the `w`-column, an artefact from `separate` splitting `o_v1_1`,`c_v1_1`,etc. into 3 columns. Here `w` was for the first character.

Comment: thank you. Can you, please, explain the logic of adding ```w```?

Comment: Please see my update. In short, `w` was an artefact from splitting the `o_v1_1`, `c_v1_1`, etc. columns.